# High-performance conflating producer/consumer pattern

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, producer-consumer, iasyncenumerable

Say you have the following interface:

```
interface IConflateWorkByKey<TKey, TValue>
{
  IAsyncEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey,TValue>> GetValues();
  void Publish(TKey key, TValue value);
}
```

This is intended to describe a work-queue like pattern. Producers can queue up items via `Publish`, and a single consumer would drain items via `GetValues`, whereby:

- Values should be conflated by key. Meaning, if producers call `Publish(1, "hello")` followed by `Publish(1, "world")` before the consumer had a chance to drain the next batch (dictionary), then the next dictionary the consumer receives would should key: 1, value: "world". The prior update (1, "hello") would be dropped/never be seen by the consumer
- `Publish` will typically be called much faster than work can be drained. In other words, invocations of `Publish` should be as fast as possible, whereby draining items is not quite as performance critical.
- It is *very* likely that in most practical cases, when the iterator return from `GetValues` is moved on by the work consumer, new items would already be available and no actual waiting is required; it would be useful to have a fast-path optimization for this case. However, an implementation would need to be prepared for this not to be the case, and then asynchronously wait for new items to be available
- There will only be one consumer (i.e.: `GetValues` will only ever be called/consumed by 1 consumer)
- Publish will not be called concurrently (though it may be called sequentially from different threads)

My current implementation looks as follows:

```
class Conflate<TKey, TValue> : IConflateWorkByKey<TKey, TValue>
{
  private Dictionary<TKey,TValue>? _buffered = null;
  private readonly object _lock = new();

  public IAsyncEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey,TValue>> GetValues(CancellationToken ct)
  {
    while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      lock(_lock)
      {
        while(_buffered is null)
          Monitor.Wait(_lock);

        var result = _buffered;
        _buffered = null;
        yield return result;
      }
    }
  }

  public void Publish(TKey key, TValue value)
  {
    lock(_lock)
    {
      _buffered ??= new();
      _buffered[key] = value;
      Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I'm open to changing the `Publish` method to return a `ValueTask` if it would be optimal for a particular implementation.

This works alright in principle, but the major problem is that the implementation of `GetValues` here is not asynchronous; the calling thread is properly blocked on `Monitor.Wait`.

I have attempted this pattern with `AsyncMonitor` from `Nito.AsyncEx` as well - but unfortunately, `AsyncMonitor.Pulse` is *significantly* too slow.

Can anyone think of a more clever implementation/pattern which is blazing fast in terms of Publishing values, while at the same allows for truly async waiting/signaling from within `GetValues`?

---

Edit: Here is another idea. I have yet to think through whether this is correct, and measure performance, but listing it here for debate. Of course still curious about other ideas!

```
class Conflate<TKey, TValue> : IConflateWorkByKey<TKey, TValue>
{
  private Dictionary<TKey,TValue>? _buffered = new();
  private readonly object _lock = new();
  private TaskCompletionSource? _tcs = null;

  public IAsyncEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey,TValue>> GetValues(CancellationToken ct)
  {
    while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      Dictionary<TKey,TValue> result;

      while(true) {
        lock(_lock)
        {
          if(_buffered.Any())
          {
            // "Fast path" - next result is already available, publish directly without having to wait
            result = _buffered;
            _buffered = new();
            break;
          }
          _tcs = new();
        }
        await _tcs.Task;
      }

      yield return result;
    }
  }

  public void Publish(TKey key, TValue value)
  {
    lock(_lock)
    {
      _buffered[key] = value;

      if(_tcs is not null)
      {
        _tcs.TrySetResult();
        _tcs = null; // "Fast path", next invocation of publish doesn't even need to call TrySetResult() if values weren't drained in between
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does publish return a value task when it's never asynchronous.  Since the task never has any useful info, just make the method `void`.

Comment: It is synchronous in _my current implementation_, but it is allowed to be async if it needed to be in another implementation, hence the signature. I do certainly agree that given the overall performance aim, the implementation very likely should be synchronous - but hey, you never know what smart people on here might come up with!

Comment: I agree with Servy. If you don't need an asynchronous return now, you might invest effort for something that you'll never need. In other words, [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it). If you ever need it, *then* add a new `PublishAsync` method to cover that future need.

Comment: Your current wording suggests that `GetValues` will only be called by a single thread, but your implementation currently looks like it supports multiple callers from different threads.  Is the single reader okay as an actual constraint, or is that just the most common situation but multiple readers needs to be technically supported?

Comment: Good question @Servy, I will add this as context to the post as well: There will only be 1 reader. An Publish will not be called concurrently as well (though it may be called sequentially from different threads)

Comment: I have amended the OP with another implementation idea, though correctness and performance are TBD. Still more than keen to hear (other) thoughts!

Comment: Don't let the buffer ever be null.  Always initialize it to an empty collection.  That moves work from the publisher to the consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation. It uses a [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1) for the case that the consumer attempts to consume a batch at a moment that the dictionary is empty:

```
class Conflate<TKey, TValue> : IConflateWorkByKey<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly object _locker = new();
    private TaskCompletionSource<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> _tcs;
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;

    public void Publish(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_tcs is not null)
            {
                Debug.Assert(_dictionary is null);
                _tcs.SetResult(new() { { key, value } });
                _tcs = null;
            }
            else
            {
                _dictionary ??= new();
                _dictionary[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> GetValues(
        [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using CancellationTokenRegistration ctr = cancellationToken.Register(() =>
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                if (_tcs is not null)
                {
                    _tcs.SetCanceled(cancellationToken);
                    _tcs = null;
                }
            }
        });

        while (true)
        {
            Dictionary<TKey, TValue> result = null;
            Task<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> taskResult = null;
            lock (_locker)
            {
                if (_tcs is not null) throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Multiple consumers are not supported.");
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                if (_dictionary is not null)
                {
                    result = _dictionary;
                    _dictionary = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    _tcs = new(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
                    taskResult = _tcs.Task;
                }
            }
            if (result is not null)
                yield return result;
            else if (taskResult is not null)
                yield return await taskResult.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation supports multiple concurrent producers, and at most one consumer.

Ideally you would need an extra method like `CompletePublishing`, so that the producer can signal than no more items are going to be produced, allowing the consumer to exit the `await foreach` loop after processing all the batches. The `CancellationToken` is not ideal for this role, because it cancels the consumer abruptly, potentially before consuming the final batch. At least that's the expected behavior for a `CancellationToken`. Compare for example the [`CompleteAdding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.completeadding) and the [`Complete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1.complete) methods of similar .NET components.